# How can I upload an image as a profile picture to my website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, console, profile

I've been trying to upload an image to my website, but it doesn't work. I want to upload an image as the profile pic of this web page.

Everytime I try to upload on the web page, the console shows this error: profile.js:4  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onchange')
at profile.js:4:20

Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<img src="placeholder.jpg" alt="profile picture" style="margin-left: 650px; border-radius: 50%;" id="profile-pic">
    <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/jpg" id="input-file">
    <label for="input-file" class="profile-pic-label">Update Image</label>
```

Javascript:

```
let profilePic = document.getElementById("profile-pic");
let inputFile = document.getElementById("input-file");

inputFile.onchange = function () {
    profilePic.src = URL.createObjectURL(inputFile.files[0]);
}
```

I tried finding a tutorial on how to do this, but they don't work.

Comment: Given the error and code shown, it sounds like the JavaScript code shown is executing before the HTML code shown has been added to the page.  The linked duplicate contains more information on this and other potential possible causes.  But any given root cause would boil down to the same underlying concept... If `getElementById` didn't find the element then that element wasn't in the DOM when that code executed.